# MySQL - group by with 2 keys

Tags: mysql, database-schema

Suppose you have a `MySQL Database Schema` with a `from_id` and a `to_id`, both representing numeric user `ID`'s. The context are text-based conversations similar to a chat.

How woud you `query`  the `database` about selecting a list of all the last messages exchanged between `user 1` and all the other users he/she had a conversation with?

Comment: Where does the GROUP BY come in if you just want to see all the messages involving that user?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @RedFilter it's not just between 2 users, it's the last message exchanged between 2 users, one being the logged user and the other being anyone else. It should retrieve a list with just one row per conversation partner.

Comment: Why do you need Group By? 'where from_id =1 or to_id' is enough

Comment: @Maksym Polshcha I need a solution, above all else. That method gets me a list of messages exchanged between the logged user and all others, not the last message exchanged by the logged user and each other user. The last one, not all of them.

Comment: Do you have any timestamp field? What do you mean by 'last'? What is the order from the first to the last record?

Comment: @Maksym Polshcha Yes, I have a timestamp for each message exchange. `ORDER BY` did nothing.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for 1 user:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE from_id = USERID1 OR to_id = USERID1 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

here `timestamp` - your timestamp field.

and for all users:

```
select text, id, ts 
from (select text, from_id as id,ts from chat union select text, to_id as id,ts from chat) T 
group by id 
having ts=max(ts)
```

here ts - timestamp

Comment: Doesn't work. Why the need for `greatest` and `least`? Those fields are ID's.

Comment: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @yoda Actually yes, I forget to add the aliases. Updated

Comment: It still doesn't work, something's not right inside the `FROM` selector.

Comment: Doesn't work. The amount of results is the expected but the data returned is incorrect and for some reason mixed (text of one row associated with the id of a different row). I ended up solving it with 2 queries and some server-side scripting. It isn't beautiful, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE from_id = USERID1 OR to_id = USERID1
```

You would want to put the columns you need in place of the "*" for better performance.

If you have a datetime field, you can then search by that as well.

Comment: That doesn't work as expected, will return a list with more than one message exchanged between the same users.

Comment: You need to explain a little better on what you are after then.  That will get all rows where the user is in from_id or to_id.  Thats all I understand from what you mentioned above.

Comment: Do you know facebook messages? When you open it, you only see 1 message for each user you had a conversation with, the last one.